# Can i run scanner on cisco packet tracer network

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

Can i run scanner on Cisco packet tracer network? It will be ideal it scanner will be nmap

Comment: scanner means????

Comment: i need to scan my virtual network created by packet tracer like real .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cisco Packet Tracer is a basic Level Simulator Software and it provide only CCNA level configurations. If you want to do advanced configurations, such as virtualization, containerization, Packet capturing you need to use advanced simulator such as GNS3.

I have heard about Netsim also good and advanced simulator. But i am not aware about Netsim.